# How do I compute this recursive function efficiently?

Tags: functions, algorithms, recursion

Let $f(x,y) = xy + f(x-1,y-1) $
where $f$ equals $0$ if either $x$ or $y$ is $0$.

Also $x,y$ belong to  $\mathbb{N}$.

Describe an efficient (less then $O(n)$) algorithm for computing $f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x, y)$ is symmetric so consider case when $y \geq x$. Let $k = y - x \geq 0$.
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x, x + k) &= \\
&= x(x+k) + f(x-1, x+k-1) = \\
&= x(x+k) + (x-1)(x+k-1) + f(x-2, x+k-2) = \dots \\
\dots &= x(x+k) + (x-1)(x+k-1) + \dots + 1\cdot k + f(0, k) = \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{x} m(m+k)\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
f(x, y) = \sum_{m=1}^x m(m+k) = \sum_{m=1}^x m^2 + k\sum_{m=1}^x m = 
\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6} + k\frac{x(x+1)}{2} = 
\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1+3k)}{6} = \\ =
\frac{x(x+1)(3y+1 - x)}{6}.
$$

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{x(x+1)(3y+1 - x)}{6}, &y \geq x\\
\dfrac{y(y+1)(3x+1 - y)}{6}, &y < x\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand this quite as well as the proof by induction.

Comment: @xrisk This answer actually derives the formula. It's well worth understanding.

Comment: Then I shall try harder to understand it :)

Comment: And I can't upvote :/

Comment: @xrisk Which part? I will try to elaborate. Also take a peek into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series

Comment: @uranix ah beautiful I understand now

Answer (score 0):

**Proposition.** If $x\ge y\ge 0$ then
$$\tag1 f(x,y)=\frac{y(y+1)(3x-y+1)}6.$$
*Proof.*
The case $y=0$ is clear.
For $y>0$ we have by induction 
$$\begin{align}f(x,y)&=xy+f(x-1,y-1)
\\&=xy+\frac{(y-1)y(3x-y-1)}{6}\\&=\frac{y(y+1)(3x-y+1)}6\end{align} $$
as was to be shown. $_\square$

Comment: Thank you. However I know only the basics of induction and have always wondered how you can think of the solution first? How did that proposition occur to you? Was it intuition?